# Which stable and modern custom ROM can I install on Galaxy Tab 10.1 (GT-P7500)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-tab

According to [the device description](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/P4_Info) at Cyanogenmod, the names for the device are:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1,
- GT-P7500,
- p4.

The [listed Cyanogenmod ROMs for this device](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=p4&type=) are all "nightly", based on Cyanogenmod 10.1.

Aren't there more stable than "nightly" builds for this device? Are there ROMs that are based on a more recent Android version than Cyanogenmod 10.1 is (or this doesn't make sense for this device)?

I do not specifically ask for an official Cyanogenmod ROM, but it is the first place I look for a open-source custom ROM.

Comment: The dates on those indicate that they're not nightly, I'm guessing they're just not feature-complete for that device.  I'm not sure what you're looking for, though; if CM isn't providing stable builds, tautologically there are not stable CM builds.  ROM recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

It Looks like there has never been an official supported stable build. That being said, you can try some of the nightly builds and hope they're stable.

Alternatively, you could have a look at some other ROMs such as ColorosOS, ParanoidAndroid, SlimROM (Check the compatibility, i've never used these on a tablet).